# How to display content of p tag of multiple divs in ul when button is clicked using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck in a situation and I need your help!
I am new to js so I am stuck with it.

basically, I am making a quiz page. when opened should only show a start button. when the button is clicked then the content within div having class questions should be displayed. at the same time when the button is clicked, I want to access the content of all p tags and display it within ul having class name as a list.

please help me.

Here is the code

```
<ul id="list">

</ul>
<button id="startbtn" onclick="myfunction()">Start </button>
<div class="questions" style="display:none">
<div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 1</p>
</div>
<div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 2</p>
</div>
<div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 3</p>
</div>
<div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 4</p>
</div>
<div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 5</p>
</div>
<div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 6</p>
</div>
</div>

<script>
    function myfunction()
    {
        var x = "";
        x=document.getElementsByClassName("questions");
          if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
          }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `x` will not be a single element that you can access directly, but instead `HTMLCollection` object. You have to iterate through it like this: `var i = x.length; while(i- -) { if (x[i].style.display === 'none') {...`

Comment: For the second task, create your `ul` element with the appropriate class, get a handle to your `p` tags and iterate as above. `let content = p[i].innerText || textContent || innerHTML; (depending on your need); then append to your ul`

Comment: alright but what about showing the content of all p tags in ul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to access the content of all p tags and display it within ul having class name as a list.

#### Idea

- Fetch all the questions
- Loop on them and create `li` tags
  -To do this, you will have to set `p`'s `innerText` to `li`'s `innerText`

  - Then You can use `ul.appendChild` to add it.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var x = "";
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("questions")[0];
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }

  const ul = document.querySelector('ul#list');
  document.querySelectorAll('.Question p').forEach((element) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = element.innerText;
    ul.appendChild(li)
  })
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">

</ul>
<button id="startbtn" onclick="myfunction()">Start </button>
<div class="questions" style="display:none">
  <div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 6</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you have solved my problem.Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array. Try this - it will get the first element with the class `.questions`

```
x = document.getElementsByClassName("questions")[0];
```

> The `getElementsByClassName` method of Document interface returns an
>   array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given
>   class name(s).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

```js
function myfunction() {
  var x = "";
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("questions")[0];
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="startbtn" onclick="myfunction()">Start </button>
<div class="questions" style="display:none">
  <div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Question">
    <p>The p tag 6</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The div is know showing when start button is clicked but what about ul?